Why SQL HAVING SUM(column) comparison with number does not work?
Try to find the continents where all countries have a population <= 25000000 from the  world table below as in Difficult Questions That Utilize Techniques Not Covered In Prior Sections.



name
continent
area
population
gdp




Afghanistan
Asia
652230
25500100
20343000000


Albania
Europe
28748
2831741
12960000000


Algeria
Africa
2381741
37100000
188681000000


Andorra
Europe
468
78115
3712000000


Angola
Africa
1246700
20609294
100990000000


...







The SQL below returns nothing but not sure why. Please advise.
SELECT 
    continent, 
    SUM(population) as total
FROM 
    world
GROUP BY 
    continent
HAVING SUM(population) <= 25000000

Without HAVING, it returns rows as below:
SELECT 
    continent, 
    SUM(population) as total
FROM 
    world
GROUP BY 
    continent
/* HAVING SUM(population) <= 25000000 */




continent
total




Africa
1016091005


Asia
4342955676


Caribbean
36149204


Eurasia
149017400


Europe
610261850


North America
518755156


Oceania
37783477


South America
407618970




None of the grouped result is less than 25000000?

Without HAVING, it returns rows as below The smallest of those is Caribbean 36149204, which is still more than 25000000.  What actual result were you expecting?

Because none of the populations added up for the continents is less than 25,000,000. The smallest is Caribbean at 36,149,204
Did you mean to have HAVING SUM(population) <= 250000000 (one more zero)
Then you would get three rows returned.
However the question asks you to return "Find the continents where all countries have a population <= 25000000. Then find the names of the countries associated with these continents. Show name, continent and population.".  So your query doesn't do this.
The correct answer can be found by looking for a continent where any of the countries populations (not the total of them) exceed the number and excluding those continents using a NOT IN
SELECT name, continent, population
FROM world
WHERE Continent NOT IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT Continent
FROM world
WHERE population > 25000000
)

There probably is also a way to do it using the ALL clause, which is probably what they wanted.
